# How to get different rows height size in Jpanel - Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm developping a java application for PC, using Swing for GUI.
When I need a Jpanel, I use the my own java class "DialogPanel"; the code of this class is at the end of this post...

Now I have to put inside my jpanel several components; my jpanel will be as a table with a single column, where every component fills one row.

The code is:

```
JScrollPane myJScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(myJList1); //myJlist is a JList object containing strings
JScrollPane myJScrollPane3 = new JScrollPane(myJList2);
JScrollPane myJScrollPane4 = new JScrollPane(myJList3);

    dialogPanel = new DialogPanel(1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 1.0 , 1.0  ); //1=1 colonna

    dialogPanel.addRow( "Title 1"   ); //row containing a title
    dialogPanel.addRow( myJComboBox1 ); //row containing a Combo box with several items

    dialogPanel.addRow( "Title 2"   ); 
    dialogPanel.addRow( myJScrollPane2 ) ; //row containing a JScrollPane

    dialogPanel.addRow( "Title 3"   ); 
    dialogPanel.addRow( myJScrollPane3 );

    dialogPanel.addRow( "Title 4"   ); 
    dialogPanel.addRow( myJScrollPane4 );

    add(dialogPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

My target is to get different rows height sizes, so to distribute the vertical space in a suitable way: 
- rows containing myJComboBox1  and the 4 Titles should occupied only the minimum space needed to wrap the content.
- rows containg the 3 myJScrollPane should occupied al the rest of the space, as much as possible (33% o remained space for each one)

I'm not able to get it, I get all the vertical space divided in 8 parts; therefore the combobox and the 4 titles have too much space (that in unusefull), while the 3 
myJScrollPane, are less big as needed

DIALOGPANEL

```
package net.gui;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

/**
 * Helps constructing nice dialog panel and windows providing easy framework.
 * Extends <code>JPanel</code> so can be used anywhere where <code>JPanel</code>
 * can be. Makes use of <code>GridBagConstraints</code> divided to max two
 * columns surrounded with a thin border around all components to provide nice
 * look to end-user. Consists of several methods <code>addRow</code> to provide
 * easy framework to developers. Thanks to this class you have identical layout
 * for all app dialog windows as well as easy way to modify them.

 * Modificata da Fausto
 */
public class DialogPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final String myClassName="DialogPanel" ; 



  //__________________________________________________________________________________
  // ATTRIBUTI
  //__________________________________________________________________________________
  private final static int spazio_dal_bordo = 3 ;
  private final static int posizionamento= GridBagConstraints.CENTER; //CENTER: Put the component in the center of its display are;  NORTHWEST: Put the component at the top-left corner of its display area; ecc... 
  private final static Insets myInsets = new Insets(spazio_dal_bordo, spazio_dal_bordo, spazio_dal_bordo, spazio_dal_bordo); //An Insets object is a representation of the borders of a container. It specifies the space that a container must leave at each of its edges
  private final static int myEmptyBorder = 5 ;
  private final static int max_num_colonne = 5 ; //numero massimo di componenti in ogni riga

  private int numColumn; //numero colonne impostate dal costruttore
  private GridBagLayout myGridBagLayout;

  /**
   * Constraints for first column (if second one is used). Is assumed that all
   * first columns (if second ones are used) contains label for a component
   * located on its right and have all the same constraints.

   * FAU: Constraints for 2°,3°,4°,5° column used sometimes. It could be a component like
   * a text field or comboBox. It could be even another <code>JPanel</code> if
   * you want. Every last component in a row uses the same constraints.
  */

  private GridBagConstraints columnConstraints[] = new GridBagConstraints[max_num_colonne] ; 




  //__________________________________________________________________________________
  //   COSTRUTTORE x righe con n colonne, dove deve essere 1 <= numColumn <= 5
  //  - La 1° colonna generalmente si usa per la label; 
  //  - Se numColumn=1 si vuole una sola colonna fatta da una sola componente nella 1° colonna  
  //  USARE QUESTO COSTRUTTORE!!!
  /**
   * Construct dialog with the ability of control a behavior of added
   * components. For more information read the default constructor description
   * <code>DialogPanel</code>
   * 
   * @param fillTypeArg
   * Si applica a TUTTE le colonne
   * This field is used when the component's display area is larger than the component's requested size. It determines whether to resize the component, and if so, how.
        The following values are valid for fill:
        NONE: Do not resize the component.
        HORIZONTAL: Make the component wide enough to fill its display area horizontally, but do not change its height.
        VERTICAL: Make the component tall enough to fill its display area vertically, but do not change its width.
        BOTH: Make the component fill its display area entirely. 

   * @param weigthXArg
   * Si applica a TUTTE le colonne
   * Specifies how to distribute extra horizontal space
   * se weigthXArg<0 (ad esempio Strings.VALUE_INT_NEGATIVE) non lo modifica
    The grid bag layout manager calculates the weight of a column to be the maximum weightx of all the components in a column. If the resulting layout is smaller horizontally than the area it needs to fill, the extra space is distributed to each column in proportion to its weight. A column that has a weight of zero receives no extra space.
    If all the weights are zero, all the extra space appears between the grids of the cell and the left and right edges.
    The default value of this field is 0. weightx should be a non-negative value.
        - 0.0: for no extra space 
        - .....
        - 1.0 for 100% resizing.

   * @param weigthYArg
   * Si applica a TUTTE le colonne
   * Specifies how to distribute extra vertical space (Resizing del componente rispetto allo spazio disponibile): 
   * se weigthYArg<0 (ad esempio Strings.VALUE_INT_NEGATIVE) non lo modifica
   * @see #DialogPanel()
   */
  //__________________________________________________________________________________
  public DialogPanel(int numColumnArg, int fillTypeArg, double weigthXArg, double weigthYArg ) {
    super();
    this.numColumn=numColumnArg;
    myGridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(myGridBagLayout);

    int index_colonna;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_num_colonne; i++) {
        if (numColumnArg>i) {
            index_colonna=  (i+1);

            columnConstraints[index_colonna] = new GridBagConstraints();
            columnConstraints[index_colonna].fill = fillTypeArg;  
            if (weigthXArg>=0) columnConstraints[index_colonna].weightx = weigthXArg; // 0.0: No Resizing ; 1.0: 100% Resising
            if (weigthYArg>=0) columnConstraints[index_colonna].weighty = weigthYArg; // 0.0: No Resizing ; 1.0: 100% Resising
            columnConstraints[index_colonna].insets = myInsets;
            columnConstraints[index_colonna].anchor = posizionamento;
        }
    }


    if (numColumnArg==1) columnConstraints[1].gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; //Specifies that this component is the last component in its column or row
    else if (numColumnArg==2) columnConstraints[2].gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; //Specifies that this component is the last component in its column or row
    else if (numColumnArg==3) columnConstraints[3].gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; //Specifies that this component is the last component in its column or row
    else if (numColumnArg==4) columnConstraints[4].gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; //Specifies that this component is the last component in its column or row
    else if (numColumnArg==5) columnConstraints[5].gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; //Specifies that this component is the last component in its column or row

    setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(myEmptyBorder, myEmptyBorder, myEmptyBorder, myEmptyBorder), new EtchedBorder( EtchedBorder.RAISED)));
  }



  //_____________________________________________________________________
  // addrow per righe con 1 colonna
  //_____________________________________________________________________


  //per aggiungere una riga fatta da: Componente  
  public void addRow(Component column1Component) {
    myGridBagLayout.setConstraints(column1Component, columnConstraints[1]);
    add(column1Component);
  }

  //per aggiungere una riga fatta da: Label  
  public void addRow(String column1Label) {
    JLabel column1Component = new JLabel(column1Label, JLabel.LEFT);
    addRow(column1Component);
  }




  //_____________________________________________________________________
  //_____________________________________________________________________



}
```

Comment: The height of a component is controlled in a number of ways, `getPreferredSize` is one, but you kind of want to avoid that if you can. `GridBagConstraints#weighty`, `GridBagConstraints#ipady` are others, even the `Scrollable` interface can help

Comment: `JList` also has a nice [`setVisibleRowCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount-int-) which it uses to provide information (via the `Scrollable` interface) to the `JScrollPane` which can change the preferred size of the scroll pane

Comment: @MadProgrammer  First of all thank you, I'll try to investigate... but I'm not so expert, therefore may be are you able to understand if there is some problem in my DialoPanel class? or may be how to add some of those nice ways suggested by you to my DialogPanelClass to get my target?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: OK, thanks, I cutted at the moment all the DialogPanel.java parts not usefull for this case...